# Encrypt and Decrypt column between Postgres SQL and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, encryption

Is it possible to encrypt a column in Postgres SQL and decrypt in SQL Server?

In Postgres SQL I used PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT to encrypt data and stored in a table.

```
CREATE TABLE encrypt_test( id integer, custname character varying(255), custname_encrypt character varying(255));

INSERT INTO encrypt_test VALUES(1, 'AAA' ,PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('AAA','P@ssw0rd'));
```

This data is transfered to SQL server through ETL. And now I need to decrypt the encrypted column from SQL server.

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'P@ssw0rd';
CREATE CERTIFICATE Certificate_test WITH SUBJECT = 'Test Encryption';
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY EncryptTest WITH ALGORITHM = AES_128 ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_test;


OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY EncryptTest DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_test;

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max), DecryptByKey(CUSTNAME_ENCRYPT)) AS Decrypted_test FROM ods.ENCRYPT_TEST;

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY EncryptTest;
```

But it doesn't work. It returns null. Can someone helps me with solution?

Comment: Master key is irrelevant here. `CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY  ... ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'P@ssw0rd'` maybe? And you probably want to specify the algorithm to `PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT` in Postgres. Also AES-128 is insecure, use AES-256

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't work. In Postgres I changed to `pgp_sym_encrypt('AAA', 'P@ssw0rd', 'cipher-algo=aes256')` And in Sql I tried `CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY EncryptTest WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256 ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'P@ssw0rd'` `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY EncryptTest DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'P@ssw0rd';` The result is still null. Not sure what went wrong.

Comment: @Pornruthai Saelee
have you got a result? I am facing the issue btw